# Get relational data in dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have studied many articles and blogs and finally conclude that I need only one base table for whole application and then many Global Secondary Indexes according to my access patterns. Now I have stuck in a problem.

My base table structure is:-

`**PK**`    `**SK**`    `**data**`

`university`    `uni_uuid`  `name`

`course`    `course_uuid`   `uni_uuid`

As you see when I will add a new course it will always have a university uuid which will save under university_uuid key with course record.

Now I want to list all the courses to Admin. So I query the dynamodb like:-

```
var params = {
      TableName: "BaseTable",
      FilterExpression:"PK = :type",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ":type": "Course"
      }
  };

  docClient.scan(params, onScan);
  var count = 0;

  function onScan(err, result) {
      if (err) {
          console.error("Unable to scan the table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
      } else {        
          resolve(result);
      }
  }
```

This successfully returns me all the added courses. Like:- 
[image]

Now my question is that how can I show University name in the column University. Currently university_uuid is displaying here. Do I need to run another query and find university name by its uuid, if so then for 100 courses I need to run 100 more queries for each course university name.

Any help will deeply appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Approaches:

1. If *university name* will not be changed in Admin you can use     denormalization and include it into *courses* table. Even if
   university name can be changed, on update you can get all corresponded courses by uni_uuid and update redundant data.
2. When you receive courses list, distinct uni_uuid and then request data from
   universities using IN clouse.